# Transfer files from a USB stick to Windows 10 IoT Core local storage

Tags: powershell, iot, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 running Windows 10 IoT Core. How can I copy files from a USB stick connected to the device to the local SD card storage? Is this possible using PowerShell?

Ideally I want to do this without the need for a UWP app running on the device and any interaction via a local GUI.

Currently when the device is running its default app and I insert a USB stick nothing happens like it does on a desktop edition of Windows 10.

[image]

To further clarify I also don't want to navigate to the devices storage via a UNC path copying files between network locations. The files have to be sourced from the USB stick.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely use PowerShell for this.

Firstly I would use the IoT Dashboard to open a new PowerShell remote management session to my Windows IoT device.

Insert the USB stick if it isn't already.

Then use the following PowerShell command to review the devices local drivers.

```
gdr -PSProvider 'FileSystem'
```

This will return a list of all drives attached. Like below.

[image]

Note; drives C, D and U are used by the device and system.

Then use a XCOPY in the PowerShell session once you know the drive letter your USB stick has been assigned. Eg. E above.

```
XCOPY E:\ C:\Data\FromUSB\
```

This will copy everything from the root of the USB stick to a folder on the devices SD card called 'FromUSB' in the Data parent directory.

Note; creating custom folder on the root of the C drive may not appear to some UI's.

Hope this helps.